# Смена контента каждые 5 секунд Laravel + Vue + AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js, laravel-5.6, laravel-5.7

Как сделать, чтобы баннер менялся на следующий каждые 5 секунд?

**Компонент**

```
<template>
  <div class="banners_box">
    <a :href="'banner.url'" class="banner_top_header"><img :src="'/storage/images/uploads/banners/'+banner.banner" alt=""></a>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import axios from 'axios'

  export default {
    el: '.banner_top',
    data: function() {
      return {
        id: 0,
        banner: []
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      this.update(),
        this.startTimer()
    },
    methods: {
      update: function() {
        axios.get('/banners/list')
          .then((response) => {
            this.banner = response.data
          })
          .catch(error => {});
      },
      getBanners: function() {
        axios.get('/banners/list')
          .then((response) => {
            this.banner = response.data
          })
          .catch(error => {});
      },
      startTimer() {
        this.interval = window.setInterval(() => {
          this.getBanners()
        }, 5000)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**Контроллер**

```
public function list()
{
  $banner = Banner::where('published', 1)->first();

  return response()->json($banner);
}
```

Comment: приложил в вопросе

Comment: update у меня возвращает первый баннер при отрисовке страницу, баннеров может быть 100, с интервалом я разобрался(обновил вопрос), а вот как делать смену не могу понять, может как отправлять id текущего? но не пойму как его брать

Comment: я там добавил таймер, может вообще не в том направлении двигаюсь? подожду вашего мнения, менять больше ничего не буду)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не нужно слать запросы для получения только одной сущности из БД.

Ниже пример постраничной зацикленной подгрузки контента: сама страница не перезагружается в браузере, а происходит лишь подгрузка содержимого в компонент Vue через AJAX с параметром `page`. При этом номер текущей "партии" содержимого `page` сохраняется в *localStorage*.

Применительно не только к баннерам: это может быть виджет новостей, ротатор изображений и др.

**Маршрутизатор**

```php
// BannerController замените на свой.

Route::get('/banners/list', 'BannerController@list');
```

**Контроллер**

```php
public function list(Request $request)
{
  // Обрабатываем запросы только по AJAX.
  if ($request->ajax()) {
    $banners = Banner::where('published', 1)->paginate(5);

    return response()->json($banners, 200);
  }

  // Запретим прямой доступ на страницу.
  abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
}
```

Примерное содержимое компонента:

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="banner" class="banners_box">
    <a :href="anchor" class="banner_top_header">
      <img :src="image" :alt="title" :title="title" />
    </a>
  </div>
<template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      // Модель текущей страницы.
      page: 0,
      // Массив всех баннеров.
      banners: [],
      // Модель текущего баннера
      banner: null,
      // Модель нашего таймера.
      timing: null,
      // Идентификатор в хранилище localStorage.
      storageId: 'so-982864'
    }
  },
  computed: {
    title() {
      return this.banner.title;
    },
    anchor() {
      return this.banner.url;
    },
    image() {
      return '/storage/images/uploads/banners/' + (this.banner.image || 'no-image.jpg');
    },
    // Ссылка, на которую будем слать запрос.
    resource() {
      return '/banners/list?page=' + this.page
    }
  },

  mounted() {
    // При монтировании компонента единожды
    // получаем номер текущей страницы из хранилища.
    // Дальше по коду только запись в хранилище.
    this.page = localStorage.getItem(this.storageId) || 1;

    // Получаем баннеры.
    this.getBanners();
  },

  methods: {
    // Получить баннеры.
    getBanners() {
      // Если вдруг вы не установили в файле `resources/js/bootstrap.js`
      axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

      axios.get(this.resource)
        .then((response) => {
          // Распакуем ответ от сервера для удобства.
          const {data, total, from, to, current_page} = response.data;

          // Добавим полученные с сервера баннеры к текущим.
          this.banners = this.banners.concat(data);

          // Поменяем номер страницы для следующего AJAX запроса.
          this.page = to < total ? current_page + 1 : 1;

          // Запишем номер текущей страницы в хранилище.
          localStorage.setItem(this.storageId, current_page);

          // Если это был первый запрос на получение баннеров:
          if (!this.timing) {
            // а) то необходимо запустить наш таймер.
            this.runTiming();

            // б) незамедлительно показать первый баннер.
            this.changeBanner();
          }
        })
        .catch(error => {
          // console.error(error);
        });
    },

    // Запуск таймера.
    runTiming() {
      // Обязательно очищаем предыдущий таймер.
      clearInterval(this.timing);

      // Запускаем новый таймер по смене баннеров.
      this.timing = setInterval(this.changeBanner, 5000)
    },

    changeBanner() {
      // Если в массиве еще есть баннеры.
      if (this.banners.length) {
        // Метод `splice` на месте удаляет из массива элементы,
        // и возвращает новый массив из удаленных элементов.
        // Даже если был удален всего один элемент, поэтому [0].
        this.banner = this.banners.splice(0, 1)[0];
      }

      // Если в массиве не осталось баннеров,
      // то нужно подгрузить еще.
      // Это отдельная конструкция `if`,
      // Не нужно объединять её с предыдущей через `else`.
      if (!this.banners.length) this.getBanners();
    }
  },

  // Это хук срабатывает перед удалением компонента,
  // не нужно пытаться его запихать в поле `methods`!
  beforeDestroy() {
    // При использовании компонентного подхода
    // обязательно удаляем наш таймер.
    clearInterval(this.timing);
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: а для чего делать смену страницы?

Comment: Самой смены страницы не будет. Запрос к БД как постраничный идет - т.е. контент частями подгружается, когда один банер остается.

Comment: а когда достигает последнего баннера?

Comment: Если у вас 100 банеров, то загружаются первые 5. Когда один остается, подгружаются следующие 5. И так далее. Когда доходит до 100 банера, загружаются по новой первые пять.

Comment: а вот вопрос, а можно перемешивать? например я перешел на другую страницу и чтобы первый баннер был другой чем на предыдущей странице?

Comment: Последний вопрос, а как роут задать при таком запросе? /banners/list?page=

Comment: @Bibika, обновил ответ.