# Как выполнять функцию раз в 5 секунд?

Tags: vue.js

```
mounted(){
        axios
        .get('/getmessages')
        .then(response =>this.messages = response.data);
    }
```

Comment: setInterval  но такой подход с запросом на бэк неправильный. сервак умрёт

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Смена контента каждые 5 секунд Laravel + Vue + AJAX](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/998252/%d0%a1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b4%d1%8b%d0%b5-5-%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%b4-laravel-vue-ajax)